# C sockets MinGW outputs lib<projectname>.exe after build (not executable)

Tags: c, eclipse, sockets, mingw

While trying to write a C program that sends UDP through a socket, I encountered the following problem:

After adding the line to create the socket

```
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

Eclipse reported the problem:

```
undefined reference to `socket@12'
```

Obviously there were libraries missing, so I added ws2_32 and wsock32.

Now it compiles and builds just fine (according to MinGW), BUT:
the output file (which was previously working) now has a "lib" prefix and is no longer executable (after doubleclick a message pops up, that says something like "%PATH%\libprojectname.exe is not a valid win32 application")

I am using Eclipse luna 4.4.1, MinGW 4.8.1, Win7 64-Bit. Libraries are from MinGW itself.

My includes are:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <winsock2.h>
```

So far I tried:

- Clean and rebuild project
- restore default (Project->Properties->C/C++-Build->Settings)
- make a new project (compiles fine until I add the libraries)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than editing your question to include your solution, please write an answer to this question, and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a "workaround": if I open the "Release"-folder (created by eclipse) in the terminal/console and recompile the files with

```
gcc -o filename.exe main.o -lwsock32
```

it works (eclipse uses a "-shared" option right after gcc, this needs to be removed)